# Discord.py bot doesn't send keycap emojis

Tags: python, emoji, discord.py

I tried creating a simple menu system and used reactions as buttons in a bot. Problem is, every time I tried to send an emoji (numeric digit emojis, one for each command in the menu), Discord spits out an error: unknown emoji. Here's the method I am using:

```
async def show_buttons(embed_object, menu, message):
    emojis = ['1️⃣','2️⃣','3️⃣','4️⃣','5️⃣','6️⃣','7️⃣','8️⃣','9️⃣']
    human_user = message.author
    msg = await client.send_message(message.channel, embed=embed_object)
    for command, emoji in zip(game_engine.buttons[menu], emojis): 
        await client.add_reaction(msg, emoji)
    res = await client.wait_for_reaction(emojis, user=human_user, message=msg)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, '{0.user} reacted with {0.reaction.emoji}!'.format(res))
    ...REST OF CODE GOES HERE...
```

`game_engine.buttons[menu]` is a list of commands that are labeled 1-9 and `embed_object` is the menu that is formatted in a specific way.

It always returns the error: `discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400): Unknown Emoji`

What do I do?

Comment: You can try using unicodes

Comment: I did, for example: "\u0031" for one, etc. But same error still occurs. The crux of my question is: which unicode for digits works on Discord?

Comment: What ```zip():``` do to the emojis?

Comment: It combines the elements of both elements into a tuple so you can 'cycle' through both simultaneously.

Comment: If you don't mind can you add that function to the question.. It's tough to answer your question without it..

Comment: No zip is a Python function - its in the main Python library, not something I made.

Comment: I think that's where the mistake is. zip function adds the elements of the two lists into pairs..

Comment: It might be that discord uses `"\N{DIGIT ONE}"` instead of the keycap digit.  You could try a command that takes an emoji string and sends back `emoji.encode('ascii', 'namereplace')`

Comment: If this is just printing to the Discord text, doesn't Discord auto change `:{emoji-name}:` to text? Either that or you could use `"{}".format('\u0031')` that might yield some different results?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Sorry, I don't understand what you mean? Could you provide a short example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer to use name escapes when working with unicode like this, because many unicode characters can look very similar.  When I take the first emoji of that list and use it in

```
def get_name(s):
    return s.encode('ascii', 'namereplace')
```

I get `b'1\\N{VARIATION SELECTOR-16}\\N{COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP}'`.  But when I make a command

```
@bot.command()
async def emojiname(emoji):
    await bot.say(get_name(emoji))
```

and run `!emojiname :one:`, I get `b'1\N{COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP}'`.

So you just need to change how you're defining your emoji literals.  I would suggest doing it like this:

```
emojis = ["{}\N{COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP}".format(num) for num in range(1, 10)]
```

Comment: Bro, you’re a genius!